# Set current item into action, depending on matchig route (KnpMenuBundle)

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

I have this builder

```
namespace Telnet\CSSBundle\Menu;
use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
class Builder extends ContainerAware
{
    public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('Main Menu');
        $menu->addChild('Главная', array('route' => 'pages_index'));
        $menu->addChild('Форум', array('uri' => '/forum'));
        $menu->addChild('Демки', array('route' => 'pages_dem'));
        $menu->addChild('SourceBans', array('uri' => '/sourcebans'));
        $menu->addChild('HLStatsX', array('uri' => '/hlstatx'));
        return $menu;
    }
}
```

How can i get this menu in any action to set current item?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this part of logic:

```
$menu->setCurrentUri($this->container->get('request')->getRequestUri());
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Knp\Menu\MenuItem::setCurrentUri() in /var/www/vhosts/css.ilimnet.ru/www/Symfony/src/Telnet/CSSBundle/Menu/Builder.php on line 14. I have been tried this yet.

Comment: What is the commit hash of `Knp\Menu` being used?

Comment: "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*",
"knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "master"